# Allow incoming Postgresql connections to a Mac from a VM

Tags: postgresql, virtualbox, firewall, macos-sierra

I'm running Postgresql 9.4 on my mac on MacOS Sierra (host) and Ubuntu 16.04 in Virtualbox (guest) and I can't seem to figure out how to allow the guest to access the host without completely disabling the firewall. I want to just allow incoming connections on port 5432 for postgres and I have added the postgres executable and psql executable to the firewall options list and without turning the firewall completely off (which I don't want to do because I'll forget to turn it back on) I can't access postgres.

Does anyone know how to add a rule to allow connections in this version of the MacOS?

As a side note, I've already configured the pg_hba.conf files and everything else to allow connections on my private network and everything works with the MacOS firewall off, I'd just prefer to have it on with the rules in place.